# In Microsoft Word how can I link to an image from the web which is saved as image once I save it

Tags: microsoft-word

In my current application, we are generating Ms Word 2016 documents for which company logo is rendered from an online URL. My requirement is that once the document is generated and saved, the image is saved in the document instead of referencing the URL.

Kindly help, it's a big issue for us.

Answer (score 1):

Simply download the image to your local computer. You can then insert it using the “Insert” tab or just drag and drop it into the document. Now the image instead of the URL is saved with the document.

Comment: The OP is probably generating the document in code, not manually through Word's UI, but still, he can download it once as suggested and then use the local copy when generating the documents.